# regex out a text from a line in R

Tags: r

I have line like this:

```
x<-c("System configuration: lcpu=96 mem=196608MB ent=16.00")
```

I need to the the value equal to ent and store it in val object in R

I am doing this not not seem to be working. Any ideas?

```
 val<-x[grep("[0-9]$", x)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If ent is always at the end then:

```
sub(".*ent=", "", x)
```

If not try `strapplyc` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) which returns only the portion of the regular expression within parentheses:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x, "ent=([.0-9]+)", simplify = TRUE)
```

Also it could be converted to numeric at the same time using `strapply` :

```
strapply(x, "ent=([.0-9]+)", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

use `sub`:

```
val <- sub('^.* ent=([[:digit:]]+)', '\\1', x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

Note this solution correctly includes `.` in the capture, as does G. Grothendieck's answer.

```
x <- c("System configuration: lcpu=96 mem=196608MB ent=16.00")

library(rex)
val <- as.numeric(
  re_matches(x,
    rex("ent=",
      capture(name = "ent", some_of(digit, "."))
      )
    )$ent
  )
#>[1] 16
```